# Gogle finance desktop shortcut stuck in weird state

Tags: chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts, google-pixel

**Siituation**

I got into very strange state after sync of my old phone (Pixel 2) to my new one (Pixel 5). The phone (or chrome) thinks that the Gogle Finance shortcut for the widget is on the desktop but it is not. What I want is the shortcut **not for the webpage** that opens in chrome but the one for **the widget app** (not sure if it iis PWA or just part of the Google app on clean Android phones).

**The problem and what I tired so far**

When I open Chrome and go to google finance website, I don't get the option to add shortcut on the desktop. I can go around that by using incognito window or Google Go app. But in both cases when I press add shortcut, it doesn't do anything. I also tried deleting all permissions and data of the google finance webpage but it didn't help. Uninstalling Chrome updates and installing it again didn't do anything as well as deleting all Chrome saved data.

**Update**

I tried to log in with different account in Chrome, that displayed the popup to add the shortcut. When I press add the shortcut, it will try to open the google finance in the default Google application and fail. The page just doesn't load. I guess it's a problem with Google app then.

The Google app has one great disadvantage which hasn't been addressed since it was created. It's not a standard app. That makes it ridiculously difficult to control when using the phone. Switching between apps very often makes the app disappear and you always lose any state of the app you had. So it is very hard for example to read news, which is one of the core functionalities (considering Google actually made it as a separate desktop when you swipe left on your home screen).

**Update 2**

Basically this whole section is useless if you open it in Chrome and makes you see much less of the screen. Not to mention that icon on your desktop for Chrome link looks much worse than the one for the "native" app.

[image]

Comment: Can you add in a screenshot of the Google Finance Widget App (if it isn't the Google Finance web page). I've been able to add to the home screen a shortcut to the 'Google Finance Page' via Android Chrome's 'Add to Home screen', and tapping on the shortcut launches the Finance page without address bar. Running Pixel 2, Android 10.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Check the update 2 section please

Comment: Google Finance did a redesign of the site. My home screen short cut link opens the current Google Finance page which doesn't have most of the items in your red box area (address bar, etc.) and even doesn't have the left side 3 line (hamburger) menu, I get the current? 9 dots in a square next to my profile icon on the right. You have some additional text after "google.com/finance", if you just tried what I quoted do you get 9 dots or the 3 line menu?

Comment: If I open the desktop shortcut it displays as on the the screenshot. The query after ...finance/ is google account user parameter, because I have more accounts, its the same for all google services like Docs, Sheets, Gmail etc.